# Unable to open Edge Cookies File with Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

we had upgraded a few days ago our Edge browser from v116 to v117 and ever since our Selenium Python Edge based web automation script has ceased to work correctly. The Edge's Cookies file is being locked by the browser so the script returns

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\Default\\Network\\Cookies'
```

Based on a similar case for Chrome ([Unable to Open Cookie File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440733/unable-to-open-cookie-file)) it seems that when Edge is started from command line with
`C:\windows\system32>start msedge --disable-features=LockProfileCookieDatabase`
the Cookies file is not being locked (I can access it with DB Browser for SQLite while Edge is open).

Any idea how can the above command be implemented as a Selenium Python `edgeOption`?

We are using Python 3.10.9 and Selenium 4.10.0

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `--disable-features=LockProfileCookieDatabase` is not working any more both on Chrome and Edge. You can test this flag in a normal browser session.

Comment: @Kendrick Li, check before test if there are no background Edge processes running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, make sure no Edge processes left. The flag is actually working. In Selenium, you'll only need to add:

```
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-features=LockProfileCookieDatabase")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options = options)
```

Now the Cookies file is accessible during automation.